# How to demonstrate prerequisites set by instantiate plugin with WP

Tags: frama-c

When using the instantiate plugin with frama-c (version 27), I'm unable to prove a precondition set by this plugin using either eva or eva and wp plugins.

This very simple piece of code illustrates the problem.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long var;

    memset(&var, 0, sizeof(unsigned long));
    return var;
}
```

Running the analyser with the following command shows no error : `frama-c test.c -eva`, but running it with the command `frama-c test.c -instantiate -eva` gives an unknown status for this precondition :

`requires valid_dest: \let __fc_len=len/8; \valid(ptr + (0 .. __fc_len-1));`

I tried without any success to prove this properties using wp and alt-ergo prover.

When I translate this precondition to the `@assert valid_dest: \let __fc_len=sizeof(unsigned long)/8; \valid(&var + (0 .. __fc_len-1));` assertion, eva is still unable to prove it but WP is (WP is still unable to prove the precondition).

When I translate this precondition to this simplified assertion `@assert valid_dest: \valid(&var + (0 .. (sizeof(unsigned long)/8)-1));`, eva is able to prove it, but neither eva nor wp are able to prove the precondition.

As a summary :

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long var;

    /*@assert valid_dest: \valid(&var + (0 .. (sizeof(unsigned long)/8)-1));*/ /*Success (EVA)*/
    /*@assert valid_dest: \let __fc_len=sizeof(unsigned long)/8; \valid(&var + (0 .. __fc_len-1));*/ /* Success (WP) */
    memset(&var, 0, sizeof(unsigned long)); /* A precondition fails with either EVA or WP if instantiate plugin is used */
    return var;
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to prove these preconditions when using instantiate plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Frama-C 27.1 Cobalt, the code that you present is entirely proved via the command:

```
$ frama-c ex.c -instantiate -then -wp
[kernel] Parsing ex.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] :0: Warning: 
  Cast with incompatible pointers types (source: uint64*) (target: sint8*)
[wp] :0: Warning: 
  Cast with incompatible pointers types (source: sint8*) (target: uint64*)
[wp] 2 goals scheduled
[wp] [Cache] not used
[wp] Proved goals:    2 / 2
  Qed:             2
```

WP does not even need to call SMT solvers. (Note: the warning are due to the original `memset` function that is still in the AST, even though properties are already proved, WP still looks at the code).

Eva cannot prove the precondition because of the `\let` construct introduced by the Frama-C kernel during the normalization, which is not supported by Eva for now. This could indeed be improved, either by removing this `\let` introduction or by adding the support of `\let` in Eva.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like an installation problem (which I do not understand yet). I tried it on another VM and it worked as you described even with frama-c 27.

Comment: Any chance to have the `\let` keyword removed in a future frama-c (or instantiate plugin) version  in order to have it proved only with eva ?

Comment: Better chances to have the `\let` keyword supported by Eva in a future version ;)